# Dynamically allocating arrays of structures of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, structure

Hi sorry for bringing it up again, I can see that there are a lot of similar problems here, but i still can't understand what i'm doing wrong. 
I have the task to write a simple database for student information, with dynamic memory allocation and structures. 
My problem is that i do not understand how to create dynamically allocated array, write information on it and how to pass it further to read it and display on screen  in another function.
I have tried writing some code and it even worked, but one day passed i try to run it and the problem appears, compiler doesn't show any significant problem with it but it just stops after entering first value (student ID).
Please help me solve what i'm doing wrong, I have no idea what am i supposed to do.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




struct student{
    char ID[7];
    char name[20];
    char surename[20];
    char addres[20];
    char phone_num[9];
};


//inputs with arrays overflow protection
student new_student(int k)
{
    student *st,*stt;
    if(k>0)
    {
        realloc(st,k*sizeof(student));
    }
    else
    {
        st=(student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
        if (st==NULL)
        {
            printf("\nERROR\nnot enough memory");
            exit(1);
        }
    }


    system("cls");

    //ID
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
        gets(st->ID);



        //check the entered ID
        if (st->ID[7]!='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered ID is to long\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st->ID[7]='\0';
        }
        else if(st->ID[6]=='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered ID is to short\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st->ID[6]='\0';
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }       
    }

    //NAME
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nenter student's name: ");
        gets(st->name);
        if (st->name[20]!='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered name is to long\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st->name[20]='\0';

            printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
            for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
                printf("%c",st->ID[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //SURENAME
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nenter student's surename: ");
        gets(st->surename);
        if (st->surename[20]!='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered surename is to long\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st->surename[20]='\0';

            printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
            for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
                printf("%c",st->ID[i]);
            printf("\n");           
            printf("\nenter student's name: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st->name[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //ADDRES
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nenter student's addres: ");
        gets(st->addres);
        if (st->addres[20]!='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered addres is to long\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st->addres[20]='\0';

            printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
            for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
                printf("%c",st->ID[i]);
            printf("\n");           
            printf("\nenter student's name: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st->name[i]);
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nenter student's surename: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st->surename[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //PHONE
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nenter student's phone number: ");
        gets(st->phone_num);

        if (st->phone_num[9]!='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered phone number is to long\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st->phone_num[9]='\0';

            printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
            for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
                printf("%c",st->ID[i]);
            printf("\n");           
            printf("\nenter student's name: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st->name[i]);
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nenter student's surename: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st->surename[i]);
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nenter student's addres: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st->addres[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }

        else if(st->phone_num[8]=='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered phone number is to short\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st->phone_num[8]='\0';

            printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
            for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
                printf("%c",st->ID[i]);
            printf("\n");           
            printf("\nenter student's name: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st->name[i]);
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nenter student's surename: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st->surename[i]);
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nenter student's addres: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st->addres[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }


    return *st;
}




void search_student ()
{
    ;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    while (1)
    {   
    system("cls");
    int choice,st_counter=0;
    printf("===MENU===\n");
    printf("1. Add Student\n");
    printf("2. Search Student\n");
    printf("3. Modify Student Record\n");
    printf("4. Generate Marksheet\n");
    printf("5. Delete Student Record\n");
    printf("6. Exit\n");
    printf("Enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

     switch(choice)
     {
            case 1:
                st_counter++;//increase array size every time entering new student's data
                new_student(st_counter);                
                break;
            case 2:
                void search_student ();
                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:
                //this will print to file later
                break;
            case 5:

                break;
            case 6:
                return 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
     }
    }

        return 1;
}
```

Comment: `if(k>0) {realloc(st,k*sizeof(student));` This expects that `st` point to a valid memory block allocated with `malloc` or similar. In reality, `st` is an uninitialized variable containing random garbage. Whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: if your code is C++ not C, use `std::vector`

Comment: you can use `std::string` in place of `char[]`

Comment: You have problems with your C-style strings. When you say `char ID[7];` that array has 7 elements and the only valid indexes are 0-6. Since C strings are NULL terminated there's only space for 6 characters and the NULL. You can't put a 7-digit id into that array and you can't write code like `if (st->ID[7]!='\0')` because 7 is not a valid index. You have the same problem with all your other strings as well. Stop doing this the hard way and just use `std::string` (and `std::vector`).

Comment: Pick one language, C or C++, and remove the tag for the other.

Comment: `realloc` _returns_ something. Use that and check its value to see if it succeeded and if the pointer did not change. See the manual.

Comment: unfortunately our lecturer don't allow us using vectors, I have to do it hard way :/

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh god thanks mate i just noticed that k should be >1 not 0 to let the first run allocate st

Comment: That alone won't help. `st` is a local variable - it's created anew, uninitialized, every time `new_student` is called. It doesn't somehow magically carry its state from one call to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so taking in consideration what you wrote i changed my code a bit. I hope it is closer to being correct.

```
student new_student(int k)
{
    student *st;
    if(k>1)
    {
        realloc(st,k*sizeof(student));
    }
    else
    {
        st=(student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
        if (st==NULL)
        {
            printf("\nERROR\nnot enough memory");
            exit(1);
        }
    }


    system("cls");

    k-=1;
    //ID
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        st[k].ID[6]='\0';
        st[k].ID[7]='\0';
        printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
        gets(st[k].ID);



        //check the entered ID
        if (st[k].ID[7]!='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered ID is to long\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st[k].ID[7]='\0';
        }
        else if(st[k].ID[6]=='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered ID is to short\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st[k].ID[6]='\0';
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }       
    }

    //NAME
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nenter student's name: ");
        gets(st[k].name);
        if (st[k].name[20]!='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered name is to long\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st[k].name[20]='\0';

            printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
            for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].ID[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //SURENAME
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nenter student's surename: ");
        gets(st[k].surename);
        if (st[k].surename[20]!='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered surename is to long\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st[k].surename[20]='\0';

            printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
            for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].ID[i]);
            printf("\n");           
            printf("\nenter student's name: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].name[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //ADDRES
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nenter student's addres: ");
        gets(st[k].addres);
        if (st[k].addres[20]!='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered addres is to long\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st[k].addres[20]='\0';

            printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
            for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].ID[i]);
            printf("\n");           
            printf("\nenter student's name: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].name[i]);
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nenter student's surename: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].surename[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //PHONE
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nenter student's phone number: ");
        gets(st[k].phone_num);

        if (st[k].phone_num[9]!='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered phone number is to long\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st[k].phone_num[9]='\0';

            printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
            for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].ID[i]);
            printf("\n");           
            printf("\nenter student's name: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].name[i]);
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nenter student's surename: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].surename[i]);
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nenter student's addres: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].addres[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }

        else if(st[k].phone_num[8]=='\0')
        {
            printf("\nentered phone number is to short\n");
            getch();
            system("cls");
            st[k].phone_num[8]='\0';

            printf("\nenter 7 digit student ID: ");
            for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].ID[i]);
            printf("\n");           
            printf("\nenter student's name: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].name[i]);
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nenter student's surename: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].surename[i]);
            printf("\n");
            printf("\nenter student's addres: ");
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
                printf("%c",st[k].addres[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }


    return *st;
}
```